# 15 Puzzle in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sliding-tile-puzzle

This is a 15 puzzle implemented in pygame. The tiles can be moved with the arrow keys or by clicking and dragging the mouse. Parts of the code that require extra like icons and sound effects files have been commented out.

## puzzle.py

````py
import pygame
from random import choice
from math import sqrt


class Direction:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Direction({self.x}, {self.y})'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.x:3}, {self.y:3}'

    def normalized(self):
        magnitude = sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2) + 0.0001  # no division by zero
        return Direction(self.x / magnitude, self.y / magnitude)

    def dot_product(self, other):
        return self.x * other.x + self.y * other.y

    def reverse(self):
        return Direction(-self.x, -self.y)


def closest_direction(displacement, directions):
    norm = displacement.normalized()
    return max(directions, key=lambda x: x.dot_product(norm))


class Puzzle:

    TILE_SIZE = 50
    SPACE_COLOR = 'black'
    TEXT_COLOR = 'black'
    TEXT_SIZE = 40
    SOLVED_COLOR = (100, 255, 100)
    BORDER_COLOR = 'black'
    BORDER_WIDTH = 5
    MOVES = {'left': Direction(-1, 0),
             'right': Direction(1, 0),
             'down': Direction(0, 1),
             'up': Direction(0, -1)}
    SHUFFLE_COUNT = 50
    LEFT_CLICK = 1

    def __init__(self, width=4, height=4):
        self.width = abs(int(width))
        self.height = abs(int(height))
        # create board
        self.board = []
        number = 1
        for x in range(self.width):
            self.board.append([])
            for y in range(self.height):
                if number < self.width * self.height:
                    self.board[x].append(str(number))
                else:
                    self.board[x].append(' ')
                number += 1
        # keep track of space so it doesn't need to be found
        self.space = (self.width - 1, self.height - 1)
        # save solution
        self.solution = str(self)
        # save history
        self.history = []

    def __eq__(self, other):
        for x in range(self.width):
            for y in range(self.height):
                if self.board[x][y] != other.board[x][y]:
                    return False
        return True

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Puzzle({self.width}, {self.height})'

    def __str__(self):
        result = ''
        for x in range(self.width):
            for y in range(self.height):
                result += f'\t{self.board[x][y]}'
            result += '\n'
        return result

    def move(self, direction):
        """ Try making a move in the given direction.
        Return whether the move changed the board"""
        x, y = self.space
        # left
        if direction == self.MOVES['left']:
            # move space up in row
            if y < self.height - 1:
                self.board[x][y] = self.board[x][y + 1]
                self.board[x][y + 1] = ' '
                # update space
                self.space = (x, y + 1)
                # update history
                self.history.append(self.MOVES['left'])
                return True
        # right
        if direction == self.MOVES['right']:
            # move space down in row
            if y > 0:
                self.board[x][y] = self.board[x][y - 1]
                self.board[x][y - 1] = ' '
                # update space
                self.space = (x, y - 1)
                # update history
                self.history.append(self.MOVES['right'])
                return True
        # down
        if direction == self.MOVES['down']:
            # move space up in column
            if x > 0:
                self.board[x][y] = self.board[x - 1][y]
                self.board[x - 1][y] = ' '
                # update space
                self.space = (x - 1, y)
                # update history
                self.history.append(self.MOVES['down'])
                return True
        # up
        if direction == self.MOVES['up']:
            # move space down in column
            if x < self.width - 1:
                self.board[x][y] = self.board[x + 1][y]
                self.board[x + 1][y] = ' '
                # update space
                self.space = (x + 1, y)
                # update history
                self.history.append(self.MOVES['up'])
                return True
        return False

    def shuffle(self, move_count):
        """ Make move_count moves, making sure each move changes the board """
        moves_made = 0
        while moves_made < move_count:
            moves_made += int(self.move(choice(list(self.MOVES.values()))))

    def is_solved(self):
        return str(self) == self.solution

    def prune_history(self):
        to_remove = []
        index = 0
        while index < len(self.history) - 1:
            # remove consecutive moves that are reverses
            if self.history[index] == self.history[index + 1].reverse():
                to_remove.extend([index, index + 1])
                index += 2
            else:
                index += 1
        for index in reversed(to_remove):
            self.history.pop(index)

    def solve(self):
        # shorten history where possible
        self.prune_history()
        # start from the most recent move
        for move in reversed(self.history):
            reversal = move.reverse()
            # make reverse move
            self.move(reversal)

    def show_history(self):
        for move in self.history:
            print(move)

    def draw_square(self, screen, x, y, color):
        # space
        if (x, y) == self.space:
            color = self.SPACE_COLOR
            if self.is_solved():
                color = self.SOLVED_COLOR
        # border
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.BORDER_COLOR, (y * self.TILE_SIZE, x * self.TILE_SIZE, self.TILE_SIZE, self.TILE_SIZE), self.BORDER_WIDTH)
        # background
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (y * self.TILE_SIZE, x * self.TILE_SIZE, self.TILE_SIZE, self.TILE_SIZE), 0)
        # text
        myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', self.TEXT_SIZE)
        textsurface = myfont.render(self.board[x][y], False, self.TEXT_COLOR)
        margin = (self.TILE_SIZE - self.TEXT_SIZE) // 2
        screen.blit(textsurface, (margin + self.TILE_SIZE * y, margin + self.TILE_SIZE * x))

    def draw(self, screen):
        for y in range(self.height):
            for x in range(self.width):
                number = self.board[x][y]
                # ignore space
                color = 'black'
                if number != ' ':
                    color = tuple([min(255, 255 * (int(number) + 5) // (self.width * self.height + 5))] * 3)  # shade of grey
                self.draw_square(screen, x, y, color)

    def show(self):
        """ Displays a puzzle graphically. """
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('Show 15 puzzle position')
        #img = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
        #pygame.display.set_icon(img)
        pygame.font.init()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.TILE_SIZE * self.width, self.TILE_SIZE * self.height))
        self.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        running = True
        while running:
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            redraw_needed = False
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        # quit
                        running = False

    def play(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('15 puzzle')
        pygame.font.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()
        #move_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('move.wav')
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.TILE_SIZE * self.height, self.TILE_SIZE * self.width))
        #img = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
        #pygame.display.set_icon(img)
        running = True
        initial_position = True
        while running:
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            redraw_needed = False
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                # mouse handling
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if event.button == self.LEFT_CLICK:
                        # start of displacement
                        pygame.mouse.get_rel()
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    if event.button == self.LEFT_CLICK:
                        # end of displacement
                        movement = pygame.mouse.get_rel()
                        displacement = Direction(*movement)
                        self.move(closest_direction(displacement, list(self.MOVES.values())))
                        redraw_needed = True
                # key handling
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        # quit
                        running = False
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        # screenshot
                        pygame.image.save(screen, "capture.png")
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_h:
                        # history
                        self.show_history()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_r:
                        # shuffle
                        self.shuffle(self.SHUFFLE_COUNT)
                        redraw_needed = True
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        # solve
                        self.solve()
                        redraw_needed = True
                    # movement
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        redraw_needed = self.move(self.MOVES['up'])
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        redraw_needed = self.move(self.MOVES['down'])
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        redraw_needed = self.move(self.MOVES['left'])
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        redraw_needed = self.move(self.MOVES['right'])
            if initial_position or redraw_needed:
                # draw puzzle
                self.draw(screen)
                pygame.display.update()
                # play sound
                #move_sound.play()
            initial_position = False
        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Puzzle(6, 8)
    p.play()

```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is really good and well-structured, well done.

The only improvement I could do is removing code repetition in the `move` function, because you had very similar code for the 4 directions, also I simplified the handling of the edge of the grid with a `try` `except` block:

```
def move(self, direction):
    """ Try making a move in the given direction.
    Return whether the move changed the board"""
    x, y = self.space
    # left
    
    direction_string_to_new_index = {
        "left" : (x, y + 1),
        "right": (x, y - 1),
        "down" : (x - 1, y),
        "up"   : (x + 1, y)
        }
    
    for dir_str in direction_string_to_new_index.keys():
        new_x, new_y = direction_string_to_new_index[dir_str]
        if direction == self.MOVES[dir_str]:
            try:
                self.board[x][y] = self.board[new_x][new_y]
                self.board[new_x][new_y] = ' '
                # update space
                self.space = (new_x, new_y)
                # update history
                self.history.append(self.MOVES[dir_str])
                return True
            except IndexError:
                return False
```

So now we have a dictionary containing the difference between the cases, and the common code is below, the `try` `except` allows to simplify the edge case handling and make it uniform for all 4 cases.

---

Another small improvement is:

```
    self.board = []
    number = 1
    for x in range(self.width):
        self.board.append([])
        for y in range(self.height):
            if number < self.width * self.height:
                self.board[x].append(str(number))
            else:
                self.board[x].append(' ')
            number += 1
```

So you mean that the last one should be different, so you could do:

```
    self.board = []
    for x in range(self.width):
        self.board.append([])
        for y in range(self.height):
            if (x, y) == (self.width, self.height):
                self.board[x].append(' ')
            else:
                self.board[x].append(str(number))
```

to make it more explicit.

---

Finally the `__eq__` function can be rewritten with the `all` built-in and a generator comprehension to make it a bit easier to understand at a glance.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough reply! I like all your improvements to my code, and the dictionary + `try` `except` of move is especially nice. About your final note with `all()`, I'm assuming you mean something like this?: `all((a == b) for a, b in zip(self.board, other.board))`

Comment: @anonymous_pigeon yes or also looping element by element, just like in your loop but with `all`

Comment: Upon trying your code out I found some errors. `(x, y) == (self.width, self.height)` should be `(x, y) == (self.width - 1, self.height - 1)`. And the `IndexError` doesn't trigger on negative indices, so you can move up/left out of bounds.

Comment: @anonymous_pigeon thanks a lot for your correction, the first one is an easy fix, but the last one is quite problematic,  I did not think about it enough. So we need to do explicit bound testing instead of the try except